# Serialize list of object with wrapper name in a field

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, yaml

I have to serialize instances of a third party Class, and these serialized objects will be used by another tool. 
So I cannot change the classes, they are in a third party library.

In my application I am using Jackson (com.fasterxml.jackson) and an ObjectMapper (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper) for the serialization.
 
My class has a List of Employee
I have a List of Employee (List) and the tool which consumes wants the employee identifier to wrap the employee object, like if it a Map. See below.

Third Party classes:

```
class Employee{
 String id;
 String location;
 String department;
} 

class Division{
 List<Employee> employees;
}
```

Currently I am using a Mixin interface to hide also some other fields that I do not need;

```
interface EmployeeMixin {
    @JsonProperty String getId();
    @JsonProperty("location") String getLocation();
    @JsonProperty("department") String getDepartment();
}
```

And add the mixin to the Object Mapper as follow: `

```
ObjectMapper myYamlMapper=Jackson.newObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
myYamlMapper.addMixIn(Employee.class, EmployeeMixin.class);
```

What I produce with object mapper is:

```
employees:
- id: "sales0051"
  location: "london"
  department: "sales"
```

While the output that I should produce is the following:

```
employees:
  sales0051:
    location: "london"
    department: "sales"
```

How can I produce the output that I need? It looks like a Map, maybe I should go in that direction but not sure how.

Comment: Are you trying to serialize to yaml?

Comment: yes, I am trying to serialize in yaml